# How to make Postfix use new IP address?

Tags: postfix

I'm using the Postfix mail server and I have 6 IPs available. I'd like to use another IP to it with my pricipal ip.

How can I do this?

For example: main IP: 66.66.66.66 other IP: 66.66.66.67

Comment: Do you want postfix listen in 2 different IP addresses?

Comment: yes when postfix send mail uses thoses 6 ips randoomly

Comment: Can you tell a bit about the background of your question? What advantages does this feature bring you?

Comment: I'd like to know the reason, too. It's quite unusual. Could you explain why are 6 IP addresses need? And why do you want postfix to listen in 2 of them and not just 1?

Comment: my vps come with thoses ips and i want postfix access to them.

Answer (score 5):

Edit the file /etc/postfix/main.cf (`sudo nano /etc/postfix/main.cf`), search for the line:

```
inet_interfaces = all
```

And change it to:

```
inet_interfaces = 127.0.0.1, 66.66.66.66, 66.66.66.67
```

Save, exit and restart postfix (`sudo service postfix restart`).

Comment: When i restart it: postfix: fatal: parameter inet_interfaces: no local interface found for 66.66.66.67 (the new ip)

Comment: @stimpack Are you sure one of your interfaces is configured with this new IP? The message says this address wasn't found in any interface. It isn't really 66.66.66.67, is it?

Comment: @Carvalho i just assigned thoses ips in my vps, i didn't make any interface, how can i make it? ( 66.66.66.67 was just example)

Comment: @stimpack Please edit your QUESTION and include the output of `ifconfig`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I configured the machine to use only IPv4.

```
cat /etc/sysctl.d/local.conf 
# Disable IP V6
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

and configure postfix to use only IPv4

```
vi /etc/postfix/main.cf
```

use only IP v4

```
inet_protocols = ipv4
```

and off-course

```
systemctl restart postfix.service
```